# C# program generates same output in file different when adding breakpoints

Tags: c#

I want to generate 160 different random users and passwords, now the code seems to work fine when I add breakpoints on user and password variables (in the for loop). But when I run my code without breakpoints, the Passwords.csv has the same output for all 160 lines. Any help is appreciated

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;

namespace WriteCSVPasswords
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string path = @"c:\temp\Passwords.csv";
            string user = null;
            string password = null;
            string[] file = new string[160];

            for (int i = 0; i < 160; i++)
            {
                user = CreatePassword(4);
                password = CreatePassword(5);
                file[i] = user + ";" + password + ";" + Base64Encode(user + ":" + password);
                user = null;
                password = null;
            }

            if (!File.Exists(path))
            {
                // Create a file to write to.
                File.WriteAllLines(path, file, Encoding.UTF8);
            }



        }

        public static string CreatePassword(int length)
        {
            const string valid = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890.+-!";
            StringBuilder res = new StringBuilder();
            Random rnd = new Random();
            while (0 < length--)
            {
                res.Append(valid[rnd.Next(valid.Length)]);
            }
            return res.ToString();
        }

        public static string Base64Decode(string base64EncodedData)
        {
            var base64EncodedBytes = System.Convert.FromBase64String(base64EncodedData);
            return System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(base64EncodedBytes);
        }
        public static string Base64Encode(string plainText)
        {
            var plainTextBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(plainText);
            return System.Convert.ToBase64String(plainTextBytes);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<strike>I doubt this has to do with breakpoints.</strike> (Code Gray makes an excellent point about the timing difference when using breakpoints, so it is related to that.)

For sure you have an issue with `Random rnd = new Random();`, since you recreate the random generator, it will start all over again and again.

I would suggest to declare `rnd` at the class level.

Comment: Probably *is* related to breakpoints, at least in the sense that if he pauses execution for a while, the time will be different, and thus a different random number will be generated. :-)

Comment: Okay, good point @CodyGray

Comment: Indeed, rnd at class level gets me the right answer. 
@CodyGray now I also fully understand why this peculiar behaviour happend, not so peculiar after all ;) Thx!